# changing displayed date of a DatePicker in onDateChanged?

Tags: android, datepicker

I'm trying to prevent the user from selecting a future date on a DatePicker.
As I'm targeting at least Android 2.3 I cannot make use of *setMaxDate*. So I tried to develope a little workaround for this:

```
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth){

        Calendar selectedDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        selectedDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

        if (selectedDate.after(now)){
            datePicker.updateDate(now.get(Calendar.YEAR), now.get(Calendar.MONTH), now.get(Calendar.DATE));

        }

}
```

But this produces a *StackOverflowError* - maybe because it's **on**DateChanged and not **after**DateChanged and the method therefore calls itself infinitely??

But what could I do instead?

Comment: You could set a breakpoint and see if you're creating recursion with stepping through the code (debugging).

Comment: @moffeltje yes I already did some debugging but it wasn't that insightful and I know that the following will sound really weird:
the overflow cannot be reproduced every time - it seems to occure randomly:
the method is started several times, sometimes the error occurs, but not always
Seems to me like if the stack already is pretty full, the overflow occurs, otherwise the method can be abandoned and nothing bad happens...